# How to change output of time command?

Tags: bash, time, output

How would you change the output of the time command from:

```
real    0m12.304s
user    0m10.187s
sys     0m1.699s
```

To:

```
12.30s
```

EDIT: Using bash (OSX)

Comment: That's a question that's easily answered by looking at the manual of your shell (at least if your shell is zsh, ksh93 or bash).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this in `.bashrc`: `export TIMEFORMAT=%Rs`

Then `source ~/.bashrc`.

Run `type time` to find out that `time is a shell keyword`. Then, run `man bash` (as bash is your shell) and search for "time".

Comment: If you just want to alter the output for a single invocation: `printf "%.2fs\n" $(TIMEFORMAT=%R bash -c 'time ...' 2>&1)`